# Variadic template array invokes undefined behavior

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, c++11, undefined-behavior

I'm trying to supply a parameter pack to initialize an array. I think it should work because:

- I'm using `sizeof...` to get the size of the parameter pack
- It's a template, and `sizeof` is a compile-time construct, so it should be known at compile-time, which means `arr` should not be a variable length array
- I'm forwarding the arguments correctly

Yet I get garbage as output and a warning. First the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args&&... args)
{
    int arr[sizeof...(Args)]{std::forward<Args>(args)()...};
    for (auto i = 0u; i < sizeof(arr); ++i)
        std::cout << arr[i];
}

int a() { return 1; }
int b() { return 2; }
int c() { return 3; }

int main()
{
    foo(a, b, c);  
}
```

Then the warning and output:

```
warning: iteration 3 invokes undefined behavior [-Waggressive-loop-optimizations]
         std::cout << arr[i];
         ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~

note: within this loop
     for (auto i = 0u; i < sizeof(arr); ++i)
                       ~~^~~~~~~~~

1230-282327744327670000-133971368332712
```

Can anyone see my mistake?

Comment: `sizeof(arr) == sizeof...(Args) * sizeof(int)`. Use `i < sizeof...(Args)` instead.

Comment: `sizeof` returns size in bytes

Answer (score 0):

```
template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args&&... args)
{
    // edit 1 : define the extent of the array once, reuse.
    constexpr std::size_t extent = sizeof...(Args);

    // edit 2 : in this case, no need to forward references since
    //          we're not actually forwarding them anywhere
    int arr[extent]{args()...};

    // edit 3 : 0 < i < extent of array
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < extent ; ++i)
        std::cout << arr[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by @Casey, `sizeof(arr)` returns the size of a variable of the type you chose for your array multiplied for the length of the array itself (in your case, `3 * sizeof(int)`).

To solve it, you can either iterate over `sizeof...(Args)` using this:

```
for (auto i = 0u; i < sizeof...(Args); ++i)
```

Or print the values while you fill the array, as it follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

template <typename... Args>
void foo(Args&&... args) {
    int arr[sizeof...(Args)] = {
        (std::cout << args(), std::forward<Args>(args)())...
    };
    (void)arr;
}

int a() { return 1; }
int b() { return 2; }
int c() { return 3; }

int main() {
    foo(a, b, c);
}
```

If the sole purpose of the function is to print the values, you can also use this:

```
int arr[sizeof...(Args)] = { (std::cout << args(), 0)... };
```

Note that the code above does not consider the case of `sizeof...(Args)` equal to `0`.
It's quite trivial indeed to do that and I'd left it out of the answer.